# memory allocation (C programming) limit on Google cloud engine

Tags: c, google-cloud-platform, malloc, google-cloud-error-reporting

The configuration of the Google cloud engine is 2 vCPUs, 13 GB memory, ubuntu-1604.

It seems that the max memory size "malloc" can allocate is a bit less than 13GB (12GB in the following example works, mallocing 12.5GB would fail..). Is this because that the virtual memory is somehow not turned on? Any other possible reasons?

```
  unsigned long input_size = 1024*1024*1024*3;
  unsigned int *h_data = (unsigned int *)malloc(input_size*sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Comment: Other programs, including the OS, consume some memory, too. Without having used google cloud engine before, I would assume that counts towards your quota.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++ programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `free` command to see how much free memory you have. It will also show how much swap space you have available.

The server might be configured for 13GB memory, but surely other things (like the OS) are using memory for other things, and not all 13GB are available for your application.

Are you expecting to be able to malloc more memory than you have physically available, using swap space?

Comment: Why would malloc be limited by physical memory?  It is asking for address space, not physical memory...

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont malloc asks for a virtual address space, but if swap space is not configured at an os level, isn't it then limited by physical resources?

Comment: @mmccaff, you are quite right, swap space is NOT configured! according to the result of free

Comment: and by default, Compute Engine instances do not have any swap space. Thank you!